# Navigate to an anchor on another page

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, anchor

I simply want to navigate from one page to a specific point on another.

I have a home page with four sections:

```
<section>
   <a name="section1"></a>
</section>

<section id="section2">

</section>

<section>
   <a name="section3"></a>
</section>

<section id="section4">

</section>
```

Section 2 and 4 feature on every page, so my nav looks like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html#section1">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">APARTMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#section3">LANDLORDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The links aren't navigating to the index page or the desired section of the index page.

Now I have:

```
<section>
       <a name="section1"></a>
</section>

<section id="section2">

</section>

<section>
   <a name="section3"></a>
</section>

<section id="section4">

</section>
```

And my navigation:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">APARTMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">LANDLORDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It is still not working.

Comment: make sure you have proper naming eg:name="section4"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you sure that you have placed the files in the same directory? I've tested the code that you have provided and it's working. However, you could try this out (a different way of giving sections an id):

```
<section>
    <a id="section1">
        CONTENT
    </a>
</section>
```

If you have done this, just use the same way of linking:

```
<a href="different-page.html#section1">Section One</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have the html files in the same directory. I have a query plugin called singlepagenav it doesn't work with this set up. can you point me in the direction of something that does?

Comment: Which jquery plugin are you using? Are you using this [single-page-nav plugin](https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav)?

Comment: Yes I'm using that one, I have multiple pages all with the same nag so when sections aren't on the same page I cannot navigate back to the appropriate page.

Comment: I've just realised I can give the link a class="external" and it navigates to the appropriate page. Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think this is an issue of having the pages in the same directory. It's an issue of the page not navigating to the other page. I'm currently experience the same problem with my website.

Answer (score 8):

Check your JavaScript code for the line that says "event.preventDefault();".

I found this in a [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) template that included this command as part of a <nav> block that makes a nice scroll to the hashtag. Once I commented it out, the links worked fine.

Comment: Sir you deserve a medal! This single line of code was driving me nuts!

Comment: Even I was using smooth scrolling piece of code, and removing that line worked fine. Great catch my friend. I'm sure this will help many people. Cheers!

Comment: This is the correct solution for those using smooth scrolling javascript. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing this issue with a legacy browser ([Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and below). Because I have tested it in Firefox, Chrome, and [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9). It's working fine. But it failed in legacy browsers.

For that, you have to use the anchor tag (`a`) instead of `div id`.

Example:

```
<a name="section1"></a>
<section>section content goes here </section>

<a name="section2"></a>
<section>section content goes here </section>

<a name="section3"></a>
<section>section content goes here </section>

<a name="section4"></a>
<section>section content goes here </section>
```

Now you can use any class name you want for your section elements...

Comment: I want to navigate to an anchor point on another page, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You need an a-name tag, please see 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The link you've sent me states "The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute instead." Which is what i am using?

Also I tried putting a <a name="section1"></a> inside section one and that did not work.

Comment: What in particular? Can you summarise here? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21600492/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

use this target="_blank" attribute in anchor tag to open page in new tabxyz