# Link to an anchor on another page

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a navbar that goes to a section of my index. It works when I use it from index, but it doesn't when I am on other page.

Here's the code of the section on my index:

```
<section id="mision-vision">
    <!-- Content -->
</section>
```

And the code of my navbar on other page:

```
<li><a href="index.html#mision-vision">Misión y visión</a></li>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What happens if you click the link `href="index.html#mission-vision` from yoursite.com/innerpage.html?

Comment: It should work but browser usually will only jump to the anchor after the page finish loading. Will it jump to the specific section of index if you give it a few seconds to load after clicking the link from another page?

Comment: Is there enough vertical content on the page to allow the page to scroll down to your anchor?

Comment: When I click, it just does not work. No redirects to anything.
I uploaded the page here: http://realthtesthost1.epizy.com/
My problem is when I try to go from "Contacto", "Proyectos" or "Apóyanos" to "Misión y visión" and "Valores" (on the navbar), which are in the index (Realth). Thanks for answer me, btw

Comment: Related: *[Navigate to an anchor on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600425/)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;


      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

It looks like your JavaScript code is causing the problem... And I don't see the reason why you applied the JavaScript code on the other pages (not index)... It's not going to **index.html**, because your script is not letting the link go to **index.html**. Your script is looking for the **hashtag** on the same document and that's the problem...

**Process 1**

You can remove that script... Because there aren't any **hash links** on your **contacts** and **Proyectos** page and that should fix it...

**Process 2**

Or if you want to have hashtag links on those pages in the future then you can add some functionality to that function, which checks if the **href** contains both the link and a hashtag and then redirects to that page using **window.location.href=** **LINK TO THE PAGE#HASH**...

**Something like this**

```javascript
if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf("#") != -1) {
    YOUR CODE with window.location = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

This should make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the `-` is causing an issue? Perhaps if you try it without the dash it might help!

Comment: Before "mision-vision", the name of id was "misionyvision" and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You get this error in the console:

> contacto.html:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

You need to use another condition in:

```javascript
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
}, 800, function(){
```

Something like:

```javascript
var href = $(this).attr("href")
if (href.indexOf("index") != -1 ) {
    setTimeout( function() { scroll(0,0); }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function() {
           window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

See the snippet below

First, you need to get the whole href of the clicked `a` link, and then check if it contains the word `index`. And if it does, *do not* prevent the default behaviour. Scroll to the top of the page, and then scroll to the anchor. let me know if it helps.

I cannot replicate the functionality here, but try it on your code.

```js
$("a").on('click', function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== "") { // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;
    var href = $(this).attr("href")

    if (href.indexOf("jsfiddle") != -1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        scroll(0, 0);
      }, 1000)

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing');
        return false;
      }, 800);

    }
    else {

      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();


      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  }
});
```

```css
div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-top: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="index.html#mision-vision">Misión y visión</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#valores">Valores</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section1">Proyectos</a></li>

    <li><a href="#section2" class="contact-us">Contacto</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3" class="donate">Apóyanos</a></li>
</ul>

<div id ="section1">
</div>

<div id ="section2">
</div>

<div id ="section3">
</div>
```