# What is the correct way to use page jump anchors?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I want to make a navigation panel that holds jump-to anchors as the links. How do I make the anchor links go to the next webpage and jump to it's assigned anchor?

I've tried assigning a unique anchor in the webpages to match those in the navigation panel. So far, the links will navigate to another webpage and jump to its anchor, once.

Then, the only links that work are those with anchors only found on the current page, even though the links tell them to go to another page and find them corresponding anchors.

The following is code contained in a .php file so that the navigation is the same across the site.

```
<html>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>About</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/prints/" id="closea"><h2>Prints</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/" id="closeb"><h2>Archival</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>VHS &amp; Reels</h2></a></li>

<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/prints/index.php#pj00" id="closec" target="_parent">Standard 1HR</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/index.php#pj05" id="closed">Shoebox Scan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tape to DVD</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/prints/index.php#pj01" id="closee">Large Format</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/index.php#pj06" id="closef">Single Scan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Repairs</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Find Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/prints/index.php#pj02" id="closeg">Mounting</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/index.php#pj07" id="closeh">Slide (Positive) Scan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Film to DVD</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Hire Us!</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/prints/index.php#pj03" id="closei">Lamination</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/index.php#pj08" id="closej">Negative Scans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cassette to CD</a></li>

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://print.sayhikc.com/">Order Online</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://weathersbyink.com/hikc/archive/index.php#pj09" id="closek">CD/DVD Copy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>

<li><a href="#"><h2>Film</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>Restorations</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>Special</h2></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>Events</h2></a></li>

<li><a href="#">Develop Only</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop I</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Canvas Prints</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Single Set</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop II</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aluminum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1-on-1 Consultation</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Double Set</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Metalic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Black &amp; White</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wood Transfer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>

<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>



===== Section: Page A ===========================================



<div class="prints01">
    <h3>Mounting</h3>
    <p>Add a unique spin to your image!</p>
    <ul>
    <li>High-quality, crisp color printing</li>
    <li>24 Hour Turn-Around</li>
    <li>Durable and Long-Lasting</li>
    <li>Professional, personal application</li>
    <li>Available in Matte and Glossy Finish</li>
    </ul>
<!-- end prints01 --></div><a id="pj03"></a>



===== Section: Page B ===========================================



<div class="prints01" style="margin-top: 12%">
    <h3>Negative Scans</h3>
    <p>Lamination is the ideal method for adding years to the life of your displayed images and graphics.</p>
    <ul>
    <li>High Gloss</li>
    <li>Maintains Image contrast &amp; Saturation</li>
    <li>Adds UV Protection</li>
    <li>Easily Cleanable</li>
    <li>24 Hour Turn-Around</li>
    </ul>
<!-- end prints01 --></div><a id="pj09"></a>

</html>
```

I expect the links to navigate from the navigation panel to its destination on pages A and B.

This can be found live at http://weathersbyink.com/hikc

Comment: Sounds like you might have some javascript affecting the events on them. With no javascript all should work fine so long as the url hash matches an element

Comment: You are correct! there was a line in my js that was preventing default behavior, thank you so much!!
event/preventDefault();`

Comment: Yup... that would do it

Answer (score 0):

I just found this answer.

"I found this in a w3school bootstrap template that included this command as part of a block that makes a nice scroll to the hashtag. Once I commented it out, the links worked fine."

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722833/8836444

Thank you @charlietfl and @mike ursitti